# Eclipse multiline comments not folding

Tags: eclipse

I just commented out some code in a project of mine using `/* */`. For some reason though no folding option (the +/- to collapse the code) appears. I went into my settings and I do have folding enabled for comments, but it doesnt seem to work. I have other sections (such as imports) that fold just fine, but comments dont seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

**First:** Remove your comments out of a method body.

**Second:** Make Sure you have Folding enabled:
Right Mouse Button click on the area to the right of your code ->
Select **Folding** -> **Enable Folding**

**Third:** *Select* your multiline *comment* and press **CTRL -** to hide selection, **CTRL +** to Expand selection.

Now you should see the plus/minus collapsing options on your pane.

[image]